# 4x4 GridLayout populate programatically in Android

Tags: android, layout, margin, android-gridlayout

I need to make a 2048 game in Android.

For the Board we need use a GridLayout and set it up programatically.

It will be a 4x4 grid just like the original game.

For the card we have to use a FrameLayout with a TextView and center it.

[Original game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4gEd.jpg)

[My result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8SpV.jpg)

This is what I already have:

```
public class Board extends GridLayout {

    private final int BOARD_WIDTH = 4;
    private final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 4;

    private Card[][] cards;

    public Board(Context context) {
        super(context);

        initBoard();
    }

    public Board(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        initBoard();
    }

    public Board(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        initBoard();
    }

    public void initBoard() {

        this.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorBoard));
        this.setRowCount(BOARD_HEIGHT);
        this.setColumnCount(BOARD_WIDTH);

        Random random = new Random();

        cards = new Card[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];

        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; x++) {

            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_HEIGHT; y++) {

                int n = random.nextInt(2);
                cards[x][y] = new Card(this.getContext(), (n * 2));
            }
        }
    }

    public void addCardsToBoard() {

        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; x++) {

            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_HEIGHT; y++) {

                GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams();
                param.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                param.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(x);
                param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(y);
                param.topMargin = 50;

                Card c = cards[x][y];
                c.setLayoutParams(param);

                this.addView(cards[x][y], 230, 230);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

-

```
public class Card extends FrameLayout {

    private int number = 0;
    private TextView txtNumber;

    public Card(Context context, int n) {
        super(context);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        txtNumber = new TextView(context);
        txtNumber.setTextSize(30);
        txtNumber.setLayoutParams(params);

        this.addView(txtNumber);

        setNumber(n);
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;

        this.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), number == 0 ? R.color.colorCard : R.color.colorCardActive));
        txtNumber.setText(number == 0 ? "" : "" + number);
    }
}
```

Anything I can do to make it look better (more like the original game).

Any tips/advice is appreciated.

Comment: `I need to make a 2048 game` ... **another one**?? And why did you choose to create a GridLayout programmatically, instead of creating a GridView in an xml layout?

Comment: @Rotwang Yes another one, it's a good way to practice right? And those are the starting instructions. Would've prefered to do it in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Add horizontal and vertical spacing to GridLayout, that is applicable to it's column and row.

```
view.setHorizontalSpacing(10); 
view.setVerticalSpacing(10);
```

Comment: Isn't this for GridView?

Comment: Yes, correct. Add padding to the params in Card class constructor as there you are setting gavity to the params(LayoutParams). It will show the UI like 2048 game UI.